# What appears between a return type and function name in a C function declaration?

Tags: c, function

I understand what a basic C function declaration means:

`return_type function_name(args) { ... }`

However, when I was working on a project that I did not write I found a strange declaration that is used repeatedly. I do not understand what it means.

Here's an example:

```
int C74_EXPORT main(void)
{
   ...  
}
```

What is that `C74_EXPORT`? What does it do, and what is this word called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not standard, so it's hard to answer in general.

It's probably a preprocessor macro, which gets replaced by something. That "something" can be compiler-dependent, it usually is.

You should read the preprocessed code to figure this out, or check the Makefile or other build artefacts for a definition of `C74_EXPORT".

Comment: indeed! I found this in the xcconfig file.. `// hide all symbols by default
// mark a function to be exported with the C74_EXPORT macro -- most likely this will only apply to the main() function
OTHER_CFLAGS = -fvisibility=hidden` -- does that `-fvisibility=hidden` mean anything, or do i need to keep digging to fully understand?